# Is it possible to remove all data from HazelcastInstance (maps & lists) at once?

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have multiple junit tests which use the same HazelcastInstance.

I have a **@After** method to delete all maps, lists manually one by one.

Is there a way to reset data in HazelcastInstance including IMap, ReplicatedMap & IList so that I can make one call only to reset my cache?

Here is what I am doing right now:

```
@After
public void afterEachTest() {
    hazelcastInstance.getReplicatedMap(MAP_NAME_A).clear();
    hazelcastInstance.getReplicatedMap(MAP_NAME_B).clear();
    hazelcastInstance.getReplicatedMap(MAP_NAME_C).clear();
    hazelcastInstance.getMap(MAP_NAME_D).clear();
    hazelcastInstance.getList(MAP_NAME_E).clear();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will probably do what you need.

```
            hazelcast.getDistributedObjects()
                     .forEach(distributedObject -> distributedObject.destroy());
```

Additionally, if you already have a reference to distributed objects, you can still use them without reinitializing like **replicatedMap = hazelcastInstance.getReplicatedMap(MAP_NAME_A)**

Comment: "... you can still use them ..." is no longer true with Hazelcast 5. Better just `.clear()` maps if you intend further using them.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to clear the whole Hazelcast instance. Other options are obviously to create a fresh Hazelcast instance for every test or to mock/fake your Hazelcast Instance for your unit tests.